# Passing JSON string as argument to Pytest

Tags: python, json, pytest, argparse

I'm using Pytest and configured my `conftest.py` to accept a few arguments:

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption(
        '--vm-name',
        required=True,
        metavar='vm-name',
        help='Name of the virtual machine the tests executes on',
        type=str,
        dest='vm-name'
    )
    parser.addoption(
        '--vm-ip',
        required=True,
        metavar='vm-ip',
        help='IP address of the virtual machine the tests executes on',
        type=str,
        dest='vm-ip'
    )
    parser.addoption(
        '--credentials',
        required=True,
        metavar='file',
        help='Path of the JSON file containing credentials',
        type=load_credentials,
        dest='credentials'
    )
```

`load_credentials` is a function that accepts a JSON string and initializes a JSON data class with the given string.

I'm using `Pyvmomi` to execute the following command in the virtual machine:

```
/bin/bash -c "echo user_password | sudo -S /usr/bin/python3 -m pytest /usr/local/auto/tests/shared/test_shared.py --vm-name my_vm --vm-ip 10.10.10.10 --credentials \'{\\"vcenter\\": {\\"username\\": \\"username\\", \\"password\\": \\"password\\"}, \\"vm\\": {\\"username\\": \\"Administrator\\", \\"password\\": \\"password\\"}}\' -rA --capture=tee-sys --show-capture=no --disable-pytest-warnings --junit-xml=/tmp/test_shared.xml"
```

However, I'm not sure why it doesn't work. I'm getting: `zsh: event not found: \\`. I assume it's because the JSON string isn't properly escaped or something. This is how I'm passing it in the code:

```
creds = Credentials(...)
creds_escaped = creds.replace('"','\\"')
f'-m pytest {test_path} --vm-name {vm.name} --vm-ip {vm.ip_address} --credentials \'{creds_escaped}\' {pytest_flags}'
```

Comment: Do you really need to use `bash -c` and/or pass your password via standard input?

Comment: @chepner I do because this is a workaround for running the commands through `Pyvomi` as sudo.

Comment: Use the `jq` utility to create JSON in shell rather than concatenating strings and variables.

Comment: "Event not found" usually comes from typing `!` in an interactive shell command, since it's the history expansion character. I don't see how you could be getting it from what you showed.

Comment: Is the backtick after `--junit-xml=/tmp/test_shared.xml"` really part of your command?

Comment: @Barmar One of my passwords contains a `!` character, but it is also escaped when passed to the machine. The backtick was corrected.

Comment: At the very least, you shouldn't need to escape the single quotes that wrap the JSON, and you only need to escape the `"`, not the backslash that precedes each `"`.

Comment: Are you sure you escaped it correctly? The error message indicates that there's backslashes *after* the `!`. To escape it, the backslash must be before it.

Comment: History expansion happens when you're typing the command interactively. It shouldn't be happening on the virtual machine. Notice that the error is coming from `zsh`, not `bash`.

Comment: Consider putting the JSON in a file, and passing just the filename in the commandlline.

Comment: Is vm a class, because you name you variable name with a dot, like vm.name?  If you use for outer f-string single quotation marks you should use inside the f-string double quotation marks.

Comment: @Barmar When I removed the `!` from my password, it worked. I wrapped the JSON in backticks (```) while escaping the quotes inside it. However, when having the `!` in my password, it breaks. I tried escaping with backslash but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling that `creds` is a JSON object, if that is the case, and if you are using `subprocess` to launch pytest. Here is a simplified solution:

```py
import json
import subprocess

cred = {
    "vcenter": {"username": "username", "password": "password"},
    "vm": {"username": "Administrator", "password": "password"},
}

cmd = [
    "python3",
    "script.py",  # An example, in place of pytest
    "--credentials",
    json.dumps(cred),
]
print("cmd:", cmd)
subprocess.run(cmd)
```

Note that I am using `json.dumps()` to do the quoting.